# Zooming on a cursor - language agnostic

Tags: canvas, language-agnostic, drawing

I implemented a zooming function in my drawing application, but it always zooms/unzooms from the top-left corner. A picture will explain better than me...
[image: zooming and viewport schema]
The drawing area is an infinite grid. The green zone is the portion of the grid that is currently shown on the screen. When the user pans the camera, the coordinates of scrollPosition change, moving the viewed area with it. When the user zooms, it changes the pixelsPerInch variable. How can I make it so that the camera actually gets centered on the cursor when I zoom? I also want to be able to unzoom, and if I just keep zooming and unzooming without moving the cursor, I should always end up at the same place.

EDIT: the variables I have are scrollPosition (object with x and y), pixelsPerInch, width and height of the actual window on the screen, cursor (x and y). I'm looking for a way to set the new value of scrollPosition when I change pixelsPerInch so that the cursor becomes the center of the new zoomed-in area.

---

## How I solved it :

I rebuilt a draggable and scalable canvas system from scratch to make sure a bug hidden in the original code wasn't the cause for my problems. Then, I took some more time to put in words and drawings what I wanted to do. This should be much more clear.[image: zooming on cursor, step by step]

I made a function which converts the coordinate of the mouse into coordinates on the underlying infinite surface. It basically takes the cursor position on the window, multiplies it by the current scaling factor and then subtracts the origin offset (what I called scrollPosition on my previous drawing).

```
function relative(canvasCoord) {
    return {x: canvasCoord.x/ppi - offset.x, y: canvasCoord.y/ppi - offset.y };
}
```

This allows me to check the cursor position both before and after applying the zoom. I can then compute the difference between the two coordinates and apply that difference to the offset. Javascript code:

```
context.canvas.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
    var canvasPoint = getCanvasCoordinates(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    var oldPoint = relative(canvasPoint);

    var scrollDirection = -Math.min(1, Math.max(-1, e.deltaY));
    ppi += scrollDirection / 10;

    var newPoint = relative(canvasPoint);
    offset.x += newPoint.x - oldPoint.x;
    offset.y += newPoint.y - oldPoint.y;
    blit();
});
```

And that's what made me realize that I was actually storing the offset in view-based pixels rather than in inches in my original code, which didn't cause any problem until I implemented zooming. Stupid mistake. But starting from scratch definitely helped me understand viewport. Here's a quick demo for HTML5 browsers only (may not work outside of chrome, I have polyfill scripts for that in my local version).

JS fiddle if you find it more userfriendly than SO snippets : http://jsfiddle.net/buu7h0be/5/

```js
context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "#5555FF";
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled;
ppi = 1; // pixels per inch
shapes = [];
offset = {x:0, y:0};
cursor = {x:0, y:0};
isDragging = false;

function Rectangle(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

Rectangle.prototype.getLeft = function() { return this.x - width/2; };
Rectangle.prototype.getRight = function() { return this.x + width/2; };
Rectangle.prototype.getTop = function() { return this.y - height/2; };
Rectangle.prototype.getBottom = function() { return this.y + height/2; };

Rectangle.prototype.draw = function() {
    context.save();
    context.translate(this.x * ppi, this.y * ppi);
    var w = this.width * ppi,
        h = this.height * ppi;
    context.fillRect(-w/2, -h/2, w, h);
    context.restore();
}

function clear() {
    context.save();
    context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    context.restore();
}

function blit() {
    context.save();
    clear();
    context.translate(offset.x * ppi, offset.y * ppi);
    for(var i=0; i<shapes.length; ++i) {
        shapes[i].draw();
    }
    context.restore();
}

// relative coordinates : in inches and relative to 0,0 on the imaginary infinite surface
// canvas coordinates : in pixels and relative to the top left corner of the canvas element

function getCanvasCoordinates(pageX, pageY) {
  var rect = context.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {x: pageX - rect.left - document.body.scrollLeft, y: pageY - rect.top - document.body.scrollTop};
}

function relative(canvasCoord) {
    return {x: canvasCoord.x/ppi - offset.x, y: canvasCoord.y/ppi - offset.y };
}


context.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    isDragging = true;
    cursor = getCanvasCoordinates(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});

context.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    var newcursor = getCanvasCoordinates(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    if(isDragging) {
        offset.x += (newcursor.x - cursor.x) / ppi;
        offset.y += (newcursor.y - cursor.y) / ppi;
    }
    cursor = newcursor;
    blit();
});

context.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    isDragging = false;
});


context.canvas.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
    var canvasPoint = getCanvasCoordinates(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    var oldPoint = relative(canvasPoint);
    
    var scrollDirection = -Math.min(1, Math.max(-1, e.deltaY));
    ppi += scrollDirection / 10;
    
    var newPoint = relative(canvasPoint);
    offset.x += newPoint.x - oldPoint.x;
    offset.y += newPoint.y - oldPoint.y;
    blit();
});

context.canvas.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 107: //add (numpad)
            ppi += 0.05
            break;
        case 109: //subtract (numpad)
            ppi -= 0.05;
            break;
        case 37: //left
            offset.x -= 10;
            break;
        case 39: //right
            offset.x += 10;
            break;
        case 38: //up
            offset.y -= 10;
            break;
        case 40: //down
            offset.y += 10;
            break;
    }
    blit();
});


shapes.push(new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100));
shapes.push(new Rectangle(400, 200, 75, 150));
shapes.push(new Rectangle(200, 400, 175, 95));
blit();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    outline: 1px solid silver;
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" tabindex="0">
    Your browser is not compatible with the HTML5 canvas.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in a language agnostic way...Work the problem backwards.

What you need to calculate is the top-left position (origin) to draw your scene such that the selected point on the scene (the cursor) is always at the same visual point on the device display.

For example, suppose your scene:

- Has its top-left origin at [0,0],
- Is scaled at 100% size,
- The selected (cursor) point is [100,50].

Working backwards, your origin must be at [-100,-50] relative to the selected point. Said another way, the top-left origin or your scene has an X offset of -100 and a Y offset of -50 relative to the cursor point.

If you scale your scene by 200%, your double-sized scene must be drawn at 2X the original [-100,-50] offsets:

```
// the new originX & originY is [-200,-100]
originX = -100 * 2.00 
originY =  -50 * 2.00
```

So if you draw your double-size scene at [-200,-100] then your cursor point will be at the same position on the device display even though your scene is twice as large as it originally was.

So for for any size your scene is scaled:

```
// calculate the required top-left of your scene for any given scaleFactor
originX = -100 * scaleFactor/100
originY =  -50 * scaleFactor/100
```

Comment: That's sounds great, I guess I just saw the mountain and didn't know where to start. I'll try that tomorrow and come back afterward.

Comment: I'll give you the "solved answer" because the phrase`so the cursor point will be at the same position on the device display even though your scene is twice as large` is what made me figure it out.

I had two errors in my scaling code which seemed to cancel each other out until I added zooming, which is actually what gave me such a hard time ^^